# Can we use Cufon-font for mobile site?

Tags: mobile, fonts, cufon

We have a site with Cufon-font and it's working fine in all the browsers except IE therefore, we've used Google font for IE css. We are now intend to create mobile site for it using same Cufon-font. My question is, Will it be ideal to use Cufon-font for a mobile site ? And will it cause any performance issues ? if  "Yes" is there are any solution for it ?

Because from research I found some bottle necks and positive result for mobile. For example

1. Opera Mini supports (to a certain degree).
2. IPhones are good at Cufon-font.

From my personal experience I've visited the current web site (which is using Cufon-font) with the Samsung Galaxy W mobile and for some detail pages it took 18 seconds load. Until it loads the page completely the fonts are displayed as normal.

Is there a way to overcome these issues ?

Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the IE issue, IE 10 supports custom fonts and that should work for you, previous versions of IE do not. As far as the time to load, that all depends on the bandwidth, the device, etc. So if you loading of over 3G its going to be slow for a large file.